# Local versioning system especially designed for documents

Tags: version-control, documentation

I have to work on some docs, I need a software that can trace all the modifications that I will make to a specific file or project (group of files): is there something like that?

The important thing is that I have to do that with a single machine so I do not need a distributed solution, I only have to work with txt files with UTF-8 charset and pdf files.

Comment: What are the important qualities of a versioning system "especially designed for documents" that wouldn't exist in a versioning system designed for source code?

Comment: If it's just text and PDF files, why specify "especially designed for documents"? IBM FileNet is good for other kinds of documents, but I would imagine that text can just be done with a version control system for code. Why not?

Comment: @OrbWeaver it can be much more simple and easy to use.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner does not seems to be what i am actually looking for, thanks anyway.

Comment: @OrbWeaver: Consider, for a moment, trying to keep Excel spreadsheets or MS-Word documents in Subversion.  "svn diff" pretty much does nothing useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use [git](http://git-scm.com/) to track my local files.

```
git init .
git add myfile1.txt myfile2.txt
git commit -m "Added first two files"
...
```

You can track everything on your local repo without needing an external one.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [DVCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control) anyway.
DVCS works great with a local repository that stays only on your local machine.
 You don't **have** to distribute, i.e. push or pull to or from other machines.

---

**EDIT:**
The most known and used DVCS are [Git](http://git-scm.com/) (as already suggested in the accepted answer) and [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/).

Comment: i was looking for some names ...

Comment: @Micro: I added one more name!

Comment: +1 for mentioning Mercurial.  It doesn't get as much attention as Git, but it's better thought out and less "hacky".

Comment: Yes, that's why I mentioned it. I'm using it as well, and I'm still [having my little problems with Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895798/how-do-i-pull-fetch-with-git-into-a-bare-repository) :-)